# ¿como transponer columnas y ocultar fila?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql

el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
select  
    ccc.Descripcion AS Grado,
    p.CodPersona AS Codigo,
    p.NombreCompleto AS Nombre,
    cc.Detalle AS Detalle,
    SUM(cc.Valor) AS Valor

from Cuenta cc
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Alumno a on cc.IdAlumno = a.CodAlumno
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Matricula m on cc.IdAlumno = m.CodAlumno
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Curso ccc on m.CodCurso = ccc.CodCurso
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Persona p on a.CodPersona = p.CodPersona

        where cc.Detalle is not null
        and cc.Valor != 0.00

        group by cc.Detalle, 
            ccc.Descripcion, 
            p.CodPersona,
            p.NombreCompleto
```

Me muestra este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que los resgitros de se vuelvan columas OJO: (ese resultado el agrupamiento de 12 registros, y solo habra 3(Descuento, mensualidad y registro) tipos de detalles para N registros) quiero que Descuento y mensualidad queden como columna y factura quede oculto.

ahora como puego mostrarlo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Siempre es descuento, y siempre mensualidad? porque de ser asi la solucion es mas simple de lo que parece..

Comment: @gbianchi si, siempre esos 3, y lo que quiero mostrar es solo dos "DEscuentos, Mensualidad" me ayudas?

Comment: ¿MySQL o SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  
    ccc.Descripcion     AS      Grado,
    p.CodPersona        AS      Codigo,
    p.NombreCompleto    AS      Nombre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cc.Detalle = 'Mensualidad' THEN cc.Valor END) AS [Mensualidad],
    SUM(CASE WHEN cc.Detalle = 'Descuento' THEN cc.Valor END)*-1 AS [Descuento]

from Cuenta as cc
    inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Alumno a on cc.IdAlumno = a.CodAlumno
    inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Matricula m on cc.IdAlumno = m.CodAlumno
    inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Curso ccc on m.CodCurso = ccc.CodCurso
    inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Persona p on a.CodPersona = p.CodPersona

    WHERE cc.Detalle IS NOT NULL
            AND cc.Valor != 0.00
            AND cc.Detalle IN ( 'Mensualidad','Descuento')

    group by ccc.Descripcion, 
        p.CodPersona,
        p.NombreCompleto;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

No hace falta realizar ninguna transposición, simplemente con un `SUM` condicional te debería alcanzar, veamos:

```
select  ccc.Descripcion AS Grado,
        p.CodPersona AS Codigo,
        p.NombreCompleto AS Nombre,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Detalle = 'Descuento' THEN Valor ELSE O END) AS 'Descuento',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Detalle = 'Mensualidad' THEN Valor ELSE O END) AS 'Mensualidad'
        from Cuenta cc
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Alumno a on cc.IdAlumno = a.CodAlumno
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Matricula m on cc.IdAlumno = m.CodAlumno
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Curso ccc on m.CodCurso = ccc.CodCurso
        inner join AlumnoDB.dbo.Persona p on a.CodPersona = p.CodPersona
        where cc.Detalle is not null
            and cc.Valor != 0.00
        group by ccc.Descripcion, 
                 p.CodPersona,
                 p.NombreCompleto
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que voy a hacer va a resolver tu problema, pero no puedo asegurar ni que sea optimo ni nada de eso:

```
select  
  ccc.Descripcion AS Grado,
  p.CodPersona AS Codigo,
  p.NombreCompleto AS Nombre,
  (SELECT SUM(cc.Valor) FROM Cuenta WHERE cc.Detalle = "DESCUENTO" and ??? GROUP BY ???) as DESCUENTO
  (SELECT SUM(cc.Valor) FROM Cuenta WHERE cc.Detalle = "MENSUALIDAD" and ??? GROUP BY ???) as MENSUALIDAD
from Cuenta cc INNER JOIN .....
```

Fijate que es facil armar una columna para cada uno de los datos que necesitas. rellene las querys con ??? porque al no saber tu modelo exacto, no se que otras condiciones necesitas, ni siquiera se si es necesario un group by (pq dependiendo de las condiciones puede que ya obtengas la suma directa).