# ¿como transponer columnas y mostrar porcentaje ? SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Este es mi código:

```
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.CodPersona) AS Numero,
    ccc.Descripcion     AS      Curso,
    p.CodPersona        AS      Codigo,
    p.NombreCompleto    AS      NombreAlumno,
    cc.Detalle          AS      Detalle,
    SUM(cc.Valor)       AS      Valor

    from CuentaCorriente cc
    inner join AlumnosBD.dbo.Alumno a on cc.IdAlumno = a.CodAlumno
    inner join AlumnosBD.dbo.Matricula m on cc.IdAlumno = m.CodAlumno
    inner join AlumnosBD.dbo.Curso ccc on m.CodCurso = ccc.CodCurso
    inner join AlumnosBD.dbo.Persona p on a.CodPersona = p.CodPersona

    where cc.Detalle is not null
    and cc.Valor != 0.00
    group by cc.Detalle, 
        ccc.Descripcion, 
        p.CodPersona,
        p.NombreCompleto
    order by Codigo
```

Me muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que me muestre de este otro modo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y no es similar a tu pregunta anterior? solo que agregando una columna mas? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104835/como-transponer-columnas-y-ocultar-fila

Comment: es similar, este es mas puntual a lo que estoy trabajando, el cambio es: tengo como 24 tipos de descuento

Comment: ¿Cómo es que obtienes el valor de 12.5?, 250 no corresponde al 12.5% de 5000

Comment: esta errado, es el equivalente en porcentaje de 5000 y 250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recupera por separado los descuentos que pueda tener un alumno en un curso (entiendo puede ser uno o más de uno) y luego combina con las filas que tengan el concepto 'Mensualidad', por ejemplo:

```
WITH Descuentos AS
(
SELECT
   ccc.Descripcion AS Curso, p.CodPersona AS Codigo,       
   cc.Detalle AS Tipo_Descuento, cc.Valor AS Valor
FROM 
   CuentaCorriente cc
   INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Alumno a ON cc.IdAlumno = a.CodAlumno
   INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Matricula m ON cc.IdAlumno = m.CodAlumno
   INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Curso ccc ON m.CodCurso = ccc.CodCurso
   INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Persona p ON a.CodPersona = p.CodPersona
WHERE cc.Detalle LIKE 'Descuento%' AND cc.Valor != 0.00    
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p.CodPersona) AS Numero,
    ccc.Descripcion AS Curso,
    p.CodPersona AS Codigo,
    p.NombreCompleto AS NombreAlumno,
    d.Tipo_Descuento AS Tipo_Descuento,
    cc.Valor AS Valor,
    COALESCE(d.Valor, 0) AS Valor_Descuento,
    COALESCE(d.Valor, 0) * 100 / cc.Valor AS Porcentaje
FROM 
    CuentaCorriente cc
    INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Alumno a ON cc.IdAlumno = a.CodAlumno
    INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Matricula m ON cc.IdAlumno = m.CodAlumno
    INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Curso ccc ON m.CodCurso = ccc.CodCurso
    INNER JOIN AlumnosBD.dbo.Persona p ON a.CodPersona = p.CodPersona
    LEFT JOIN Descuentos d ON ccc.Descripcion = d.Curso 
        AND p.CodPersona = d.Codigo
WHERE cc.Detalle = 'Mensualidad' AND cc.Valor != 0.00
ORDER BY Codigo;
GO
```

Comment: me manda 100 registros de cada uno

Comment: y si hago el group by y suma, el resutaltado de la suma me da 50 000.00

Comment: y solo tengo 10 registros en la DB que sumados me dan 5000.00